# ASP.Net user forgets password and answer to security quest ion

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership

This does happen from time to time. Is there an easy way to programmatically reset the password for a user without having to know the answer to the security question or their original password. I have a very cumbersome way of doing it now.

I open the aspnet_Membership table and bring up my row and their row only. I copy my password and password salt in to their row. I have now set their password to be the same as mine. I can now call the two lines of code below to reset their password to whatever they want it to be.

Is there a way I can reset their password without having to set it to mine first?

Greg

```
Dim user As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser("{Their username}")
user.ChangePassword("{My password}", "{Their new password}")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`ResetPassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that as:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(UserIdToChangePass);

if (mu != null)
{
    string sLastPassword = mu.ResetPassword();
    mu.ChangePassword(sLastPassword, txtNewPassword.Text);
}
```

Comment: For me, string sLastPassword = mu.ResetPassword() throws an exception of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: passwordAnswer". This is why I changed to my cumbersome way. Greg

Comment: @user1091524 Please read on MSDN the remarks and make the small changes where they needed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2(v=vs.110).aspx  - you maybe can temporary turn off the `RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` OR programmatically change your database and add a well known password as you do now, but not by hand.

Comment: I know about RequiresQuestionAndAnswer as a part of <membership>, but I guess I want to be able to override at times when someone has forgotten both the password and answer. Just reset the password and move on. Greg

Comment: @user1091524 You can also direct read the secret answer from the database and give it to ResetPassword.

Comment: It is hashed. I suppose I could test this, but will ResetPassword take the hashed form of the answer? it doesn't seem like it would. Greg

Comment: @user1091524 Ok, the last you have is to programmatically add a known hash password, and use it.

Comment: Yep, I had the same exact thought on lunch. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit of a hack, but it works. I got the password and salt for the generic password 'Password!'. I update the the membership table for the user with that hashed version of Password!. I then use that to reset their password to a new password because I now know that their current password is Password!.

Now if I could just figure out why I must click the button twice for it to work. The first time nothing fires and then I click again and it works.

Greg

```
    Try
        'Get the user
        Dim user As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(Server.HtmlEncode(txtUserName.Text))

        'Build a SQL string to reset their password to Password!
        Dim sSQL As String = "UPDATE  [dbo].[aspnet_Membership]"
        sSQL &= " SET [Password] = 'p4p+zOnsA+if4+F7oVcmR8Y0yiM='" 'Hash for Password! 
        sSQL &= " ,[PasswordSalt] = 'URJfTNqAlfa+5TsNxFe7Uw=='" 'Salt for Password!
        sSQL &= " WHERE [ApplicationId] = '{Your Application ID Here}' AND UserID = '" & user.ProviderUserKey.ToString & "'"

        'Reset their password in the aspnet_membership table to Password!
        Dim dbconn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("{Your Membership Connection Here}").ConnectionString)
        dbconn.Open()
        Dim dbCommand As SqlCommand = dbconn.CreateCommand
        dbCommand.Connection = dbconn

        dbCommand.CommandText = sSQL
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbCommand.Dispose()
        dbconn.Close()

        'Now reset their password to the new password useing Password! as the known password
        user.ChangePassword("Password!", Server.HtmlEncode(txtNewPassword.Text))
        lblMsgInfo.Text = "The password was reset."

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMsgInfo.Text = "Error: " & ex.Message
    End Try
```